# AVAudioPlayer doesn't work with (NSString *)filename

Tags: objective-c, audio, mp3, avaudioplayer

I want to implement a player that plays sounds and/or music. I have these two methods:

```
-(void)playSound:(int)soundIndex
{
  NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[SoundFxFilenameArray objectAtIndex:soundIndex] ofType:@"mp3"]];

  if(FxPlayer)
  {
    [FxPlayer release];
    FxPlayer = nil;
  }

  [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient error:nil];

  FxPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
  [FxPlayer play]; 
}

-(void)playMusic:(NSString *)filename
{
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:filename ofType:@"mp3"]];

  if(MusicPlayer)
  {
    [MusicPlayer release];
    MusicPlayer = nil;
  }

  MusicPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
  [MusicPlayer play];
}
```

Now, `[[SoundPlayer sharedManager] playSound:FXIndex_Default]` works just fine. When I try to play music though, `[[SoundPlayer sharedManager] playMusic:@"music_file_name_here"` just doesn't do anything. Note that both the sound file and the music file are of the same format (mp3).

Also, the "sharedInstance" is because I implemented the singleton pattern for this audio player.

Any pointers or ideas on what is so wrong in my code so that I can play sounds but not music?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `fileURLWithPath` instead of `URLWithString` in `playMusic`:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:filename ofType:@"mp3"]];
```

`URLWithString` expects a complete URL such as "file://path/to/file.mp3" as argument, `fileURLWithPath` expects just a file path.

Comment: Oh, man, it was exactly that! Thanks for the explanation as well! :)

Comment: @sebkomianos: `URLWithString` works with all kinds of URLs, "http:", "file:" etc., so it has to know the URL scheme. `fileURLWithPath` is a special method for file URLs.